# Remove circle selected in button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have to do this task. I need to remove the shadow/circle when selecting a button. The shadow is when the cursor is on it.

You have the image here

[image]

The code that I have is this:

```
<NavButton disabled={loading || rowsLength < size} onClick={handleNext}>
  <AngleRightIcon size={24} />
</NavButton>
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: can you also add `css` of `<NavButton>` ?

Comment: const NavButton = styled(IconButton)({
  width: 64,
  height: 64,
});
Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: try ‘background: transparent;’

Comment: But the shadow is one the cursor is on the button, any idea how to remove it?

Comment: I mean does `background: transparent;` give you expected result ? when you want this to be on button active ? also can you make a codesanbox for this issue where we can see the problem, I don't understand what you mean by But the shadow is one the cursor is on the button

Comment: adding background transparent didn't fix it. I mean that the button is active with a circular shadow when I try to click on it. So I want to remove that effect. When you click on the arrow, it sends you to a new page. The code is the one a pasted it. Thanks!

Comment: can you make a [codebox](https://codesandbox.io/) for this, where I can see the problem

Comment: I think I need to remove the focus accessibility feature. Sorry but I don't know how to create a  codebox. But I don't know how to apply that style in my code. Could you help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253587/discussion-between-madan-bhandari-and-mariadev).

Comment: sure, I'm in the chat. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned css in comment, update your style with this:

```
const NavButton = styled(IconButton)({
  width: 64,
  height: 64,
  '&:active': {
    background: 'transparent',
  },
  '&:hover': {
    background: 'transparent',
  },
});
```